# I don't know the list of CSS in TwentyTwentyone

Tags: html, css

I am creating an HP using Twenty Twenty one in WordPress.
I'm writing CSS in a child theme because I want to reduce the header margin (Padding), but I can't change it by any means.

```
/*
style.css
 Theme Name: child
 Template: twentytwentyone
*/

.site-header {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
header#masthead.site-header.has-logo.has-menu {
    padding: 0;
}
```

```
<?php
//function.php
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');
    function theme_enqueue_styles(){
        wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css', array('parent-style'));
    }
?>
```

Would you please let me know if there is anything to add to the above code?
Also, even if I edit the code of TwentyTwentyOne's Theme directly (even if I edit the parent theme directly), the margin (Padding) of the client page does not become small at all, so I could not do anything, so I asked a question.

Currently, I am connecting to SFTP with FileZilla and uploading the css file, and since I can confirm the code edited locally on WordPress, I think that the code itself is reflected.

Comment: When inspecting the page, is your styling applied? it might get overruled by the default css applied to the header. also: `the margin (Padding) of the client page`. margin and padding are 2 different things. if the header has margin, adding `padding: 0` won't do anything

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I solved it.